# Connect through two VPN clients

Tags: vpn

What exactly happens if I connect through two VPN clients on my laptop? For example, I connect using Cisco Any Connect, and then use another VPN client (such as HotSpot Shield or proXPN) to connect through another tunnel.

Will the actual data be decrypted at the first server/site and be in plaintext/visible? I mean, will this happen: data is encrypted at my laptop, sent to server 1, decrypted, then encrypted, sent to server 2 where it's finally decrypted. I doubt it, because the second tunnel is through *my client to server 2*, not *server 1 to server 2*.

Or will it be a tunnel in a tunnel? So: data is encrypted and encapsulated twice at my laptop, decrypted at server 1, but is not yet in plaintext, and would be routed to server 2 where it'll be finally decrypted.

Or will the laptop simply pick one tunnel (the latter?) for a normal client-to-site VPN? Or will the second connected not even establish in the first place?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

**A typical VPN client** works like this: it connects to the server, and then it instructs the operating system to give him all packets which are to be sent to any address in a given set. For instance, let's assume that the VPN client advertises that it should handle all packets meant for 10.0.0.0/8 (i.e. all IP addresses which start with "10"). When the OS sees a packet which should go to address "u.v.w.x", it checks whether "u" is "10"; if yes, then it gives the packet to the VPN, which does its magic with it and forwards it, under heavy encryption/MAC/whatever to the server; otherwise, the packet is emitted "to the Internet" as the OS would have done without the VPN client.

Details on how this system is implemented depend on the VPN implementation (e.g. it may declare specific "routes"; or it could intercept all outgoing packets with firewalling rules and redirect the packets it is interested in;...).

If you have two VPN clients and their "advertised sets of addresses" do not overlap, then chances are that they will live together nicely *at the IP level*: each will grab the packets for its own virtual network, leaving the other packets untouched. However, they might also fight for the "interception resources" which may result in the first VPN client to be wholly deactivated.

On the other hand, if both VPN advertise overlapping sets of addresses, then trouble is pretty much guaranteed. If you are lucky, the second VPN will refuse to run with an explicit message. Otherwise, one of the clients may take precedence, possibly intermittently, and things will be weird and confusing. Possibly, one VPN server will receive the packets which were due for the *other* VPN, thus incurring a severe data leak.

**There will be trouble with DNS**. Applications and humans do not want to deal with *IP addresses* but with *host names*. The DNS converts host names to IP addresses. A VPN being a "virtual *private* network", it uses names which are not visible to the worldwide, Internet DNS. Therefore, a VPN client will not only intercept IP packets, but also the name resolution system, and redirect some (if not all) of name resolution requests to a dedicated DNS server on the VPN.

Your two VPN clients will compete for that redirection. Things *might* just work well if the clients manage to redirect requests for just some domains. But chances are that hijinks will ensue. Some names for one VPN will probably cease to be convertible to IP addresses, resulting in reduced functionality. Possibly, one VPN will receive name resolutions for the *other* VPN, so not only is the functionality broken (because the DNS in one VPN will not know what to do with names from the other VPN) but some private data leaks from one VPN to another (host *names* are rarely very sensitive, but that's still a leakage).

In this last situation, the VPN which receives name resolution requests for private names of the other VPN is in ideal position to respond with forged DNS answers and redirect all traffic from the other VPN to itself.

**So don't do that**. Running several VPN clients concurrently is a source of trouble, hard-to-diagnose failures and potential data leaks.

---

**To avoid issues with multiple VPN**, you should endeavour to use more "controlled" forms of VPN. For instance, a *SOCKS proxy with ssh*. This would allow you to run one Web browser which redirect all its traffic to another host (the "VPN server") while leaving the rest of the machine (and, crucially, other browser instances) unaltered. See [this answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/23561/authenticating-a-proxy-server-over-https/23584#23584) for instance. Some purists say that such proxying is *not* a VPN, but for many practical purposes (anything which is Web-based, really), this is functionally equivalent. See also the alternative with port-based tunnels.

I used to do that a lot at one time (a dozen or so port-based tunnels, and also SOCKS proxying, and it was all working well). The SOCKS solution works well for name resolution too: the name resolutions requests from the Web browser will go through the tunnel, to be resolved on the other side (i.e. in the VPN), without touching the local DNS configuration. Port-based tunnels require a static local name declaration.

Comment: Sheesh. I had totally forgotten DNS in my answer; kudos for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1):

> For example, I connect using Cisco Any Connect, and then use another VPN client (such as HotSpot Shield or proXPN) to connect through another tunnel.

I assume that you are using both clients on a single computer, so you have two parallel tunnels, not one inside the other (as you would have if you connected from your computer to Server1, and *there* you fired up VPN2 to connect Server1 with Server2).

In the first (parallel) scenario, each VPN client will create its own virtual interface, with its own address, netmask, remote gateway and related routing.

Any data sent *through a tunnel* will be encrypted by that tunnel and no other, so the question becomes: how does your computer determine *what* data send down *which* tunnel?

This is done through routing rules on the client. For example, you might receive address 192.168.42.17/24 on VPN1, and address 192.168.77.13/24 on VPN2. If you tried to link with host .42.33, you would go through VPN1, and VPN2 would know nothing of it.

Now, 192.168.42.0/24 might only be the private network used between you and the server, i.e. the one assigned by Server1 to all its VPN clients; the real network served by Server1 could be 10.20.30.0/24, and therefore Server1 would *also* add a routing to 10.20.30.0/24 through 192.168.42.1; then when you try to connect to 10.20.30.137, that connection would flow through VPN1, be encrypted, and again VPN2 would not even know this is taking place (why should it?).

**Possible problems**: what happens if *both* VPN1 and VPN2 broadcast a route for the same subnet, which does not correspond to the same physical hosts? E.g., you have two offices with the *exact same configuration*, and ServerAtOffice1 has address 10.20.30.137, while ServerAtOffice2 has address 10.20.30.195. Since those two networks *never talk to each other*, this ensues no conflicts at all.

Until you fire up VPN1, which tells that 10.20.30.0 goes through VPN1, and then also fire up VPN2, which tells that, no, 10.20.30.0 goes through VPN2 and no one else.

What happens in that case depends on the VPN client. A smart client would tell you "Hey, I was about to route 10.20.30.0 but, what do you know?, this route already goes somewhere else, and maybe I could notify this to my System Administrator, just in case you were up to something frisky".

Or you might have two stupid clients, and the last to overwrite the other's configuration requests stands to profit.

Or something even weirder might go on, and connections might *start* working and then die messily a few packets later.

A final possibility could be that both clients want to set up a *default* route - one for addresses you don't know about - through themselves.

Then, when connected to Server1, all your Internet navigation could be encrypted through Server1. Then you *also* fire up VPN2, and the "default" navigation gets routed through VPN2. Now all your Google queries about Customer #1 are routed, in clear, through Customer #2's network, firewalls, packet analyzers and so on and so forth; which could spell no end of troubles, depending on your role and the two customers' amicableness of terms.

## Tweaks

> How could I do other version, not the two clients in parallel? If I
>   have DD-WRT running on a router ALPHA which has a PPTP VPN server running,

to whom you connect from client `CHARLIE`,

> can I make it connect to VPN server BRAVO? Is that chaining on
>   tunnelling? In any case, the final server would see my traffic coming
>   from the router in between, right? –-  László

We can have two scenarios here (I have added names to your machines).

In the first scenario ALPHA is itself **also** client DELTA of server BRAVO. In this case the packet from CHARLIE is normally *masqueraded* by server ALPHA, so that any client served by BRAVO sees the packets as coming from DELTA. This can be difficult or impossible to do if BRAVO's clients have the same scheme as ALPHA's clients, for in that case you might have an ambiguity as to who has, say, address 192.168.112.17; is it the 17th client of ALPHA or is it the 17th client of BRAVO?

In the second scenario ALPHA just routes, so that BRAVO is now available to you via ALPHA's VPN. So you open **a second VPN tunnel inside the first one**, and get assigned a **second IP address** by BRAVO. You are now at the same time both client CHARLIE of server ALPHA *and* (unbeknownst to ALPHA) client DELTA of server BRAVO.

BRAVO's clients will see you as DELTA, while BRAVO will of course be aware that you are ALPHA's client CHARLIE.

Again you can have trouble here if the addresses and their routing conflict (e.g. the connection to BRAVO relies on a default route, *but BRAVO itself installs its own default route upon connect*, replacing the one by ALPHA).

Also (even if nowadays this is becoming irrelevant), the load on ALPHA is lower in this second scenario, and the load on your CPU is proportionally higher (all packets to BRAVO's network are encrypted by BRAVO-Driver, then passed to ALPHA-Driver and *reencrypted*, before finally being passed to ADSL-Driver and sent on their way).

Comment: How could I do other version, not the two clients in parallel? If I have DD-WRT running on a router which has a PPTP VPN server running, can I make it connect to another VPN server? Is that chaining on tunnelling? In any case, the final server would see my traffic coming from the router in between, right?

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically, it will be a tunnel within a tunnel. The first tunnel is between your computer and the first VPN endpoint. The second tunnel goes through the first tunnel to the first VPN endpoint where it exits the first tunnel and then goes to the second VPN endpoint.

I say theoretically because I think it depends how the VPN clients set up the connections and routing table. The second VPN client could set up the routing table and metrics in such a way that even if you have the tunnel in tunnel theoretical setup from above, data will be sent to the first tunnel and the second tunnel will not be used at all.

Answer (score 0):

#### Two cases, two possibilities:

You could initiate a client connection **from** your *laptop* **to** the *cisco*, than a second connection **from** the *cisco* **to** the final target:

```
<laptop> ---- <cisco> ... <cisco> ---- <final>
```

In this case, datas will transit in clear at *cisco* host.

Or you could initiate a client connection **from** your *laptop* **to** the *cisco*, than a second connection **from** your *laptop* **to** the final target:

```
<laptop> ---- <cisco> .... <final>
<laptop> ----------------- <final>
```

In this case (while both encryption tunnels are initiated successively from the same host: the *laptop*), it will be a *`tunnel within a tunnel`* and *cisco* won't see unencrypted datas.

**Nota:** In this,

```
----  mean encrypted connection and
....  mean unencrypted (local or network) connection
```

Comment: Well, according to the other answers, this is not what typically happens, because each client would be trying to route the packets through its tunnel, not through each other.

Answer (score -1):

Here is simple test If Tunnel inside tunnel is made or not

first turn on VPN1 and check your IP address online. It should show your VPN1 IP.
now flush your cache and all things and try connecting to your VPN2, if it is connected then check your IP online .If after connecting to your VPN2, online IP checker shows your VPN1's IP then Tunnel inside tunnel is not established. So ther exists a problem between two VPN clients