# VPN connection through VPN connection using Virtual Machine

Tags: vpn, openvpn

I read online that there is such thing as DoubleVPN what basically means

> PC -> vpn1 -> vpn2 -> internet

However, its stated here:
https://www.bestvpn.com/privacy-news/chaining-vpn-servers-double-vpn/

That it can be done with vpn providers who support such vpn chaining "Double-hop VPN services".
They said another way to do the vpn chaining yourself would be with virtual machine.
Basically having one VPN client running as you would and then creating an virtual machine and running another VPN client in it and doing your things on that virtual machine.
In short:

> PC -> VPN 1 -> Virtual Machine  -> VPN 2 -> Internet

I have very little knowledge of how vpn works in general and trying to find a way around of learning everything by making a post here.

**The first question would be if this really works and is safe
method?**

Thomas Pornin answer from this post:
[Connect through two VPN clients](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/31030/connect-through-two-vpn-clients/31031)

states (in short) that:

> Don't do it, simply brings more problems.

However difference here is that the OP there did not use virtual machine.

**Secound question would be, if it is working and is safe after all, could it be possible to avoid
virtual machine between and just use OpenVPN for example to do the job on one os?**

Thanks!

Comment: What are you getting with the VM in the middle of everything? What's the purpose of it?

Comment: I don't know for sure because I am not educated technically on that area.
What I read so far ( and since it was an random persons answer, don't relay on it much ) that if you would run 2 vpn clients together, instead of doing a tunnel inside of a tunnel, they will fight for the packages. This is something what I'm using based on logic of mine, then I would be to run through virtual machine, vpn client has no choice put to go tunnelling inside the tunnel. It could not physically fight over packages with other client since it can't reach it through virtual machine, right?